# Slice on date/time with a step value

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a date/time Series:

```
indices = pd.date_range(start='feb 01 2020', end='nov 30 2020', freq='D')
sr=pd.Series(index=indices, data=np.random.randn(indices.shape[0]))
```

I can extract Wednesdays:

```
selected = pd.date_range(start='march 01 2020', end='sept 30 2020', freq='W-WED')
print(sr[selected].head())
```

> ```
> 2020-03-04   -0.378698
> 2020-03-11    1.616860
> 2020-03-18   -0.738064
> 2020-03-25    0.375743
> 2020-04-01   -0.233976
> Freq: W-WED, dtype: float64
> ```

I just wants to simplify the slice in the usual form `[start:end:step]`, but I don't know how to express `step`. I did various attempts, e.g.:

```
sr['march 01 2020':'sept 30 2020':'W-WED']
```

> ```
> '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
> ```

Comment: You can't, but assuming you have all days, you could do: `sr['march 04 2020':'sept 30 2020':7]` (note the start of the slice that is a Wednesday)?

Comment: The step must be an integer.

Comment: Thanks you both @mozway and `Bricam` for mentioning it's not possible. So with a slice of dates/times, `step=n` just selects one out of n timestamps in the slice, whatever their values or their order.

Comment: This is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sr[sr.index.dayofweek == 2]
```